# UISlider iOS app custom values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

```
  let step: Float = 10000.0
  let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
  sender.value = roundedValue
  ProgressLabel.text = "\(sender.value) sqft"
```

I have a single slider that needs to give 2 values when moved once the values are to be given through hard code.
I am not able to produce the desired result.
it should be exactly like we have in our design. Single Slider. When I slide each step will show the values as mentioned in the list.

Comment: Show some code which you tried

Comment: i have an uislider action, i need values like that,    
$5,000 - $10,000 sq.ft.
$10,000 - $25,000 sq.ft.
$25,000 - $50,000 sq.ft.
$50,000 - $100,000 sq.ft.
$100,000+ sq.ft.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana simple drag and drop slider to the storyboard, then ibaction to the respective view comtroller in which this code : et step: Float = 10000.0
        let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
        sender.value = roundedValue
        ProgressLabel.text = "\(sender.value) sqft"

Comment: Edit your question with theses info, format the code if necessary. Explain more carefully what isn't working and what's the expected result.

Comment: @Larme i need the slider to return two values which is one is the min value along with it the max value and they are $5,000 - $10,000 sq.ft.
$10,000 - $25,000 sq.ft.
$25,000 - $50,000 sq.ft.
$50,000 - $100,000 sq.ft.
$100,000+ sq.ft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the label to show custom values, like $5,000 - $10,000 sq.ft. $10,000 - $25,000 sq.ft. $25,000 - $50,000 sq.ft. $50,000 - $100,000 sq.ft. $100,000+ sq.ft

If this is the case, why son't you use a simple switch statement or an if -else if - else block and add the logic there ?

Something like:

```
if (sender.value) < 0.05 {
    progressLabel.text = "too low"
} else if (sender.value) < 0.2 {
    progressLabel.text = "$5,000 - $10,000 sq.ft."
} else if (sender.value) < 0.8 {
    progressLabel.text = " $10,000 - $25,000 sq.ft.."
} else 
    progressLabel.text = "$100,000+ sq.ft"
}
```

Comment: yes the question is same. how to make the switch conditions?

Comment: and what do i put the initial or min value? puttin the same code shows 100,000 on scrolling when my value on the slider is 10,000

Comment: Yeah so update the if else conditions for whatever ranges and values you want. This is just the sample code. Did you say scrolling ??